# how to filter the contents of a listbox based on a text box value

Tags: javascript, html

i have a html form which contains the following elements

1) a list box (containing a list of filenames)

```
  s1.txt2013
  s2.txt2013
  s3.txt2012
  s4.txt2012
```

2) a text box (user enters a pattern say 2013)

3) a button

by default list box contains a the above mentioned 4 files names.

when a user enter a a text in the text box (say for example he eneters 2013 in the text box), and press the button, then the list box contents should be filtered out according to the text mentioned in the text box

so in this case after clicking the button, list box should only contain two values (i.e. only those values in which 2013 appears).

```
s1.txt2013
s2.txt2013
```

how can i do this.
 i did the following way..
i am using a javascript function which will take all the option values of the list box in a javascript array. now i am not able to search the array for 2013 and populate the same list box with the values containing 2013 in in.

can anyone tell me how to do this?

Comment: is using jquery is not an option?. Another thing can you share the function that you are using?

Comment: jQuery is ok or only in javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you need two listboxes (select tags), one of them be hidden as main data source and one of them visible for users, you can use following code and add `onclick="buttonClicked()"` to you button attributes.

```
function buttonClicked () {
    var textbox = document.getElementById('YOUR TEXTBOX ID'),
        listbox = document.getElementById('YOUR SELECT ID'),
        mainListbox = document.getElementById('YOUR MAIN SELECT ID');

    listbox.innerHTML = '';
    for (var childIndex = 0; childIndex < mainListbox.children.length; childIndex++) {
        var child = mainListbox.children[childIndex];
        if (child.innerHTML.search(textbox.value) != -1) {
            option = document.createElement('option');
            option.innerHTML = child.innerHTML;
            listbox.appendChild(option);
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: i used the above code.. but its not working.. i thing the eventlistener part is not getting executed. here is the code i have used. can you make it work somehow?

Comment: Aha! You want to click on button to filter list, OK, check out my solution one more time, I'm editing it.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using .test? To me this would be a good approach.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_test.asp

```
<script>

var str="Hello world!";
//look for "Hello"
var patt=/Hello/g;
var result=patt.test(str);
document.write("Returned value: " + result); 

//look for "W3Schools"
patt=/W3Schools/g;
result=patt.test(str);
document.write("<br>Returned value: " + result);

</script>
```